# Why is my swapfile on btrfs suddenly not active?

Tags: mount, swap, fstab, btrfs

I have created a swapfile /swap on / btrfs with:

```
touch /swap
chattr +C /swap
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=2048 
mkswap /swap && chmod 600 /swap && swapon /swap
```

It works and mounts fine and all is good when I check with `swapon -s`It's mounted in fstab. However, after a while the swapfile is no longer mounted and working when I do `swapon -s`and I have recreate the file to get it to work again. I do not know exactly when this happens since I do not notice that my system with lots of is needing swap. How can I find out when and what happens and possibly make sure the swapfile stays active and mounted?

My fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=546fa6af-ca9c-419f-9883-ba182e35969d /               btrfs   ssd,space_cache,compress=zstd,noatime,defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=EAE2-20E2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=546fa6af-ca9c-419f-9883-ba182e35969d /home           btrfs   ssd,space_cache,compress=zstd,noatime,defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
/swap                                       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Please add output of `/etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: This could happen e.g. if you restored some snapshot. I am using a swapfile on a separate subvolume.

Comment: I attached fstab to my post. I only restore snapshots in my home directory. I do use 'btrfsmaintenence' on my partions as described here: https://github.com/kdave/btrfsmaintenance#quick-start

Comment: There is no need to do this kind of maintenance. Probably that is why the problem appeared.

Comment: So btrrfsmaintenance is a useless application? I have to do trim somehow on my SSD though.

Comment: Trim is done automatically in Ubuntu without any "useful" applications. I didn't look into it, because I see no reason to use any kind of this sort of application.

Comment: btrfsmaintenance is installed and used by default on distributions like OpenSUSE so I think it has it's uses if it's configured correctly according to disk and usage. What I wondering is whether  maintenance tasks on btrfs may change file attributes on my swap file.

Comment: I am now making sure that there's no maintenance done on the file system except for fstrim which is run by default on Ubuntu. Still the swap-file becomes inactive after a while and I have to recreate it. This time the swap-file "lasted" for three weeks, but yesterday when I checked (swapon -s) I got nothing.

Comment: Nothing happens "by itself" Ny swap file never disappears ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 "By itself" means that it happens without any processes scheduled or performed by me. I think fstrim is run though. I know that balance will mess up the swap file so there are ways to render it unusable. I have it set to me "nocompress" which I've read should be done on compressed drives like mine.

Answer (score 0):

One showstopper are in your case:

- swapfile - must be NODATACOW (i.e. also NODATASUM, no compression)

See:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230304121225/https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Swapfile.html